# Do we need both [completable-future] and [completion-stage], and which one should we keep?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

I recently noticed that we have both [completable-future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/completable-future) and [completion-stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/completion-stage):

[completable-future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/completable-future) (<strike>26</strike> 71 watchers, <strike>468</strike> 1116 questions)

> In Java 8, a Future that may be explicitly completed (setting its value and status), and may include dependent functions and actions that trigger upon its completion.

[completion-stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/completion-stage) (<strike>0</strike> 2 watchers, <strike>9</strike> 39 questions)

> Java 8 common API interface of a possibly asynchronous computation, that performs an action or computes a value when another CompletionStage completes. Note: this tag is a bit different from `completable-future`, which is a default implementation of this CompletionStage API

Of course, usage of the latter is quite low, but this tag would actually be applicable for all [completable-future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/completable-future) questions since it is an implementation of that interface.

Conversely, `CompletableFuture` is the JDK implementation of `CompletionStage`, and thus the de facto standard ([there is another one](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/completion-stage), but I'm not sure it is used much). Moreover `CompletionStage` has a [`toCompletableFuture()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#toCompletableFuture--) method, so it's coupled with it anyway.

Does it make sense to keep both tags? Should we make them synonyms?

I don't think we should keep both, as questions using only one of them are just losing visibility.

Comment: Do we need either?